# Top and left positioning not respected on some websites

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an extension to overlay on a page and create a see-through layer to expose only certain elements on the page. Something similar to the one here - [In this link](https://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/zGVWjN)

First, for the overlay, I created a div `overlay` with `position: fixed`  `background: transparent` and `pointer-events: none` and `z-index: 9999` so that this is the topmost layer. I then created another div ("shadow") which uses box-shadow for see-through with top & left based on the target element's `getBoundingClientRect()`.

I'm having an issue where "shadow" div doesn't respect top and left positioning on some websites. I needed to add margin-top and margin-left for some of them. Why is that?

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.shadow {
  top: 3935px;
  left: 1008px;
  width: 26.7344px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: rgba(184, 20, 129, 0.6) 0px 0px 0px 141.421vmax;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
  <div id="shadow" class="shadow">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `position:absolute;` on your class `shadow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.shadow` div does not have a `position` style, which means that it is probably defaulting to `position: static`. `top`, `left`, and so on do not apply when the element is using `position: static`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top):

> When position is set to static, the top property has no effect.

Because of this, I'm not sure how you got this to work on any websites at all. In the example you provided, the element with the `box-shadow` also has `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Not all web browsers have the same css basic rules so what you need is something like reset.css or normalize.css - To create the same experience cross-browsers.

PD: Also you can play around with `opacity` (which admits a value between 0 and 1)

Reference:

reset.css - https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

normalize.css - https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Hope helps :)